# Wordpress User Roles & Entry Form with PayPal

Tags: forms, wordpress, paypal, roles

I have a unique client opportunity upcoming and I need some help with how I want to handle the project. Without giving too much away, here is what I'm facing:

I need visitors to this soon-to-be Wordpress site. They need to be able to register as normal and will be setup as 'Subscribers' upon registration per usual. However, here's the twist that I can't get around:

I need these 'Subscribers' to be able to fill out an entry form on the site to entry a contest that has a "processing fee." The client wants to collect the fees via PayPal. So, I need the 'Subscribers' to be fill out this form if they want to enter and on submission the form goes through PayPal to collect payment - If successful, then the form the 'Subscriber' filled in will be placed in the backend moderation que for an Admin to review the submission. I need these submissions to act like they came from a 'Contributor' though so they hit the Admin que.

Basically, visitors will be able to send in these submissions to try to get their stuff posted to the site to be voted on by other users.

I'm desperate as these project is a really good one but will be starting soon.

Comment: How often do you need to charge subscribers? One time only or recurring billing? Does admin need to approve every transaction?

Comment: On each form submission, there would be a one-time charge tied to it via PayPal. EACH submission requires this payment to be made before it sends the form into the system. It's a one-time charge, zero recurring and the Admin only needs to approve the actual post content.

These submissions are basically site content. The form is a glorified 'Add a Post' form but has a charge tied to it. I just need something so a user who wants to submit something to be voted on can submit it, pay the one-time submission fee and have their post hit a que for the Admins to review it before it makes the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to store user's payment information (not credit card number), so that user won't have to enter same infomation again everything he/she posts a content.

You want PayPal Express, Payment Pro or Payflow Gateway, so that you can use DoReferenceTransactionReq. Basically, you save the very first transaction id of user's payment. And keep using it (as referrence) for next payments. Please make sure they approve your account first; they sometime do not approve depending on your business.

Authorize.Net also has same feature called CIM (Customer Information Manager). It is more easier to store/access user profiles and payment profiles. But it is up to you.

Good luck!

Comment: So, I could have all visitors register as Subscribers at first. Then allow users to stay "Voters" (Subscribers) or become Contributors themselves. And then perhaps just make the submission form that is tied to the PayPal fee be visible to the latter. I believe that could work. Now, I begin researching how to make a custom form that is actually a PayPal, content submission form for the site that hits the back-end Admin moderation feed. This project is becoming more and more exciting, I like it! Thank you again for the advice! If anyone has anything else to contribute, please do. @Win = #WINNING

Comment: If you have question, please feel free to ask. Or if this answer your question, please mark it as Answer so that it'll be useful for others.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I realize that "hiding" the 'Submit Content' option for default registered users would be a bad thing. Leaning on the fact that users would all be willing and able enough to transition from Subscriber to Contributor is a little too much to ask, sadly. :P What are the drawbacks to having new registered users default to Contributor? I can hide all those options and change URLs for security. But, on the front end I can still allow users to 'Submit Content' and pay the PayPal fee each form submission... right? Allowing them to be Voters as well as Contributors. (Thx!)

Comment: I would not ask user's credit card when they sign-up. Let them be voters, but only collect payment when they submit form. You can always persuade voters to submit form or let them submit a couple of fee forms. Otherwise, you won't have enough voters in your site. It is just my two cents. Good luck!

Comment: Just FYI, get approval from PayPal first. They something do not approve depending on your business type.

Comment: Wouldn't ask for credit card on the site. I was thinking I would have the form, then on 'Submit' it would transfer them to the PayPal Gateway for payment information and processing. Basically, there will be a nice big "Submit Content" button and I want registered users to be able to fill one out if they wish to pay the fee and submit for voting. So, the PayPal is essential. I will look into the PayPal approval as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you want user to pay at PayPal, you want 'PayPal Express' which provides SOAP API. It is easier to implement than 'PayPal Standard'.

Comment: Without a doubt, you've made this project easier for me to sink my teeth into. Thank you so much Win!